# How to draw the phase portrait if two of the eigenvectors are (0,0,0,0) and eigenvalues are positive in one case and negative in other?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory

I have two eigenvalues and they are 2wsqrt(2) and -2wsqrt(2) where w is the angular frequency of the system. Both of the eigenvectors corresponding to these eigenvalues are (0,0,0,0) so how can one sketch a phase portrait for it?

Comment: You have made a mistake in finding eigenvectors, because by definition the zero vector is never an eigenvector.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out again. In addition how can you draw phase portrait of some system if you have more than 3 dimensions? (in my case it's 4)

Comment: Alternatively, if you feel like including $0$ as an eigenvector, it's an eigenvector of **every** matrix with **every** eigenvalue, so it's not much use and you need to find some non-zero eigenvectors.